# Crystal report SDK JRC Passing parameter giving error Error code:-2147217394 Error code name:missingParameterValueError

Tags: java, crystal-reports

When I am trying pass paramaters from crystal report SDK and export my report to PDF. It is stand alone application so I can't user crystalreportviewer options but it is keep giving me error
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKParameterFieldException: InternalFormatterException---- Error code:-2147217394 Error code name:missingParameterValueError My code is given below please help

```
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.DatabaseController;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ParameterFieldController;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.data.IConnectionInfo;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.exportoptions.ExportOptions;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.exportoptions.ReportExportFormat;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException;
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) throws ReportSDKException, SQLException,      FileNotFoundException, IOException{
try{

ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
reportClientDoc.open("Report.rpt",0);
ParameterFieldController paramController = reportClientDoc.getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController();

paramController.setCurrentValue("","P_DP",new Integer(22));
//Here I was calling switch database code 
 ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream)reportClientDoc.getReportSource().export(ReportExportFormat.PDF);
 IOUtils.copy(byteArrayInputStream, new FileOutputStream("new.pdf"));

 reportClientDoc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: I just swap the code setting parameters with switching database It starts working Now it is look like below code      
//Here I was calling switch database code
      ParameterFieldController paramController = reportClientDoc.getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController();

     paramController.setCurrentValue("","P_DP",new Integer(22));

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it starts working by just moving setting parameter code to above line. we need to set parameter before opening the report.

```
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.DatabaseController;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument;
import com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ParameterFieldController;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.data.IConnectionInfo;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.exportoptions.ExportOptions;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.exportoptions.ReportExportFormat;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKException;
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) throws ReportSDKException, SQLException,      FileNotFoundException, IOException{
try{

ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();

ParameterFieldController paramController = reportClientDoc.getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController();
paramController.setCurrentValue("","P_DP",new Integer(22));

reportClientDoc.open("Report.rpt",0);


//Here I was calling switch database code 
 ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = (ByteArrayInputStream)reportClientDoc.getReportSource().export(ReportExportFormat.PDF);
 IOUtils.copy(byteArrayInputStream, new FileOutputStream("new.pdf"));

 reportClientDoc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: I realize this is a very old comment, however the solution appears to be no longer valid with the current Crystal Reports API and results in the error "com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.lib.ReportSDKClientDocException: The document has not been opened.---- Error code:-2147215349 Error code name:docNotReady"